# JQuery/ Flask - send data from server to browser as JSON

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

Firstly excuse my ignorance, I'm very new to all this.

My problem is that I'm trying to send json data stored in a mongodb of coordinates to a client browser. I have a python module which uses Twitter's Streaming API to store into the DB. This works fine, but when I try to send this to the client it displays nothing, evenhough I can see server terminal getting more data. I've not used Flask or JQuery before, so have based it on the example at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/.

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from pymongo import Connection 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_reader')
def reader():
    db = Connection().tstream
    coll = db.tweets_tail
    cursor = coll.find({"coordinates.type" : "Point" }, {"coordinates" :1},tailable=True,timeout=False)
    ci=0
    while cursor.alive:
        try:
            doc = cursor.next()
            ci += 1
            print doc
            print ci
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return jsonify(ci, doc)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port= 8888)
```

This is my html client side:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
       $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_reader', 
       function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });

</script>
<h1>Coordinates</h1>
<p>
   <span id=result>?</span>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm hoping that has new coordinate data is received it pushes this to the client.

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's the URL you're using for the getJSON call. Not sure what $SCRIPT_ROOT is, but this should be a URL and not a file location.

Comment: I used file location as in the example. They state the reason for using file location is: If you are developing the answer is quite simple: it’s on localhost port something and directly on the root of that server. But what if you later decide to move your application to a different location? For example to http://example.com/myapp? On the server side this never was a problem because we were using the handy url_for() function that could answer that question for us, but if we are using jQuery we should not hardcode the path to the application but make that dynamic, so how can we do that?

Comment: Not sure who "they" is but this has to be a URL. `getJSON` speaks HTTP not file I/O. I've never seen this work with anything but a URL. I could be wrong. As for your concerns about moving the site, you won't use the whole domain, just the bit after the hostname. In your case, it's likely just `/_reader`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your line
    return jsonify(ci, doc)

Are you sure this returns correctly ? The arguments should be in dictionary format. Can you try this instead

```
return jsonify(dict(ci=ci, doc=doc))
```

Comment: Hi I've tried that, still nothing returned to client browser.

Comment: What is being printed for ci and doc.

Comment: When I run program it prints: "{u'_id': ObjectId('50994de11d41c80f20b4fa0d'), u'coordinates': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-0.20583153, 51.42092323]}}
1" It prints this each time the twitter streaming api finds the coordinate data

Comment: If I now try to do "console.log(data[0]);" in the browser the page doesn't load.